# Bluetooth audio streaming issues with Droid X

Tags: bluetooth, audio, motorola-droid-x, streaming

When I stream audio from my Droid X via bluetooth, the playback is very stuttered.  The audio skips approximately every 30 seconds to a minute.  Each skip lasts about 0.5 to 1 seconds.

This is the case for every app that I've tried so far (Pandora, Stitcher, Google Music).  Whether I'm listening to talk or music doesn't seem to make a difference, and in all cases, playback works flawlessly over the phone's speaker.

The bluetooth device I'm using is my car's Ford SYNC.  My wife's iPhone 4 streams brilliantly, so I don't think it's the car.

Does anyone know of any workarounds or fixes for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by turning off Wifi on my phone.  Not sure why having Wifi turned on would be a problem, but I don't get any skipping when Wifi is off.